# Select TRUE or FALSE where a relationship exists or not

Tags: mysql, sql

table1

```
    id  name

    1   john
    2   mary
    3   bill
    4   carrie
```

table2

```
    id  thing

    1   ball
    2   socks
```

tableJoin

```
    id  name_fk    thing_fk

    1     1           1
    2     4           2
```

I want a query that selects ALL the names in table1 and a 'relationship exists in table2' column from tableJoin as follows:

tableResult:

```
columnName     columnRelationshipExists

 john            YES
 mary            NO
 bill            NO
 carrie          YES
```

Comment: can you show an example about your tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT   name, EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tableJoin WHERE tableJoin.name_fk = table1.id)
FROM     table1;
```

Or else a grouped outer join:

```
SELECT   table1.name, COUNT(tableJoin.name_fk) > 0
FROM     table1 LEFT JOIN tableJoin ON tableJoin.name_fk = table1.id
GROUP BY table1.name;
```

See them on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4151d/1).

Comment: Awesome :D Didn't need to try the second option. Thank you @eggyal

Comment: The second option returns the inversion of the first, I'm guessing that's not intentional?

Comment: @MatW: No it doesn't, it's just that the `GROUP BY` operation causes the results to be sorted by `name` which happens to *look* like the results have been inverted.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
SELECT t1.name, tj.id IS NOT NULL
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN tableJoin tj ON tj.name_fk = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.name
```

I've not tested, but my feeling is that `IS NOT NULL` will prove faster than `EXISTS(SELECT)` and `COUNT`

Comment: What if there are multiple records in `tableJoin` with the same `name_fk`?

Comment: Good spot, have added a `GROUP BY`

Comment: Okay, but now the value of `tj.id` that is tested for `IS NOT NULL` is an indeterminate one selected from amongst the group.  Whilst one might take the view that this shouldn't matter because either all records should be not-null or there will be only one `NULL` record (depending on whether the join predicate was successful or not), it's somewhat flaky - and would be invalid in any other RDBMS.  Hence why I opted to `COUNT()`.

Comment: Fair points. However, as you allude to, ambiguity isn't an issue; the OP simply wanted to know of the existence (or not) of a relationship (and is using MySQL).